# Conversion character for typedef'd element types?

Tags: c, type-conversion, typedef

Say I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int el_type;

int main(void)
{
  el_type n;

  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("%d\n", n);

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a conversion character I can use in place of `%d` in this situation to print n?

Comment: `%u` for `unsigned int`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: `typedef` doesn't create a new type. All it does is define an alias. After ``typedef unsigned int el_type`, `el_type` and `unsigned int` are indistinguishable.

Comment: You could define macros `#define PRI_el_type "u"` and `#define SCN_el_type "u"`, and then use `scanf("%" SCN_el_type, &n);` and `printf("%" PRI_el_type "\n", n);`, similar to the usage of the macros defined by `#include <inttypes.h>`.